# Eloquent relation for 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to display the loans granted to a certain user specifically on user.show.

here's the table for loan amounts
[image]

here's the Grant loan table

[image]

now on user.show i'd like to display the loans granted to that user

on my loan amount model,

```
public function grantLoans()
{
    return $this->manyToMany('App\LoanAmount','id','amount_id');
}
```

on my GrantLoanAmount Model

```
public function user() //just update this. this line works
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','user_id');
}

public function amounts() //just update this. this line works
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\LoanAmount','id','amount_id');
}
```

on my userController

currently I only have this,

```
public function show($id)
{
$grantLoan = GrantLoanAmount::where('user_id',$id)->get();
?????
}
```

how can I the amount? form grant_loan_amounts table?

thank you!

Comment: Look into eloquent relationship has-many-through https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: If i am not wrong... Isnt it is sit between one to many relationships????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `User` model, a `LoanAmount` model and a `GrantLoanAmount` model and a User can be granted more than one loan amount then this should work

```
//User model
public function loan_amounts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\LoanAmount',
        'App\GrantLoanAmount',
        'user_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'amount_id'
    );
}
```

Comment: hi after I apply this, this error appear, SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'loan_amounts.grant_loan_amount_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `loan_amounts`.*, `grant_loan_amounts`.`user_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `loan_amounts` inner join `grant_loan_amounts` on `grant_loan_amounts`.`id` = `loan_amounts`.`grant_loan_amount_id` where `grant_loan_amounts`.`user_id` = 13) i am calling the amount by this, {{$user->loan_amounts}}

Comment: @Lito I've edited the answer. I tried similar to how I implemented